# How do I fade from a color to an image in the header?

Tags: image, colors, header, gradient, fade

I have the color #FF6600 that I would like to fade into an image horizontally starting with the color on the left of my header and going into the image on the far right.  How can I do this in css? do I have to use webkit or no? thanks!

Comment: gradients are new in css3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/gradient

Comment: right, and Ive found several different formats for creating a horizontal gradient, just wondering if its possible to have a background image for the header then have a gradient on top of that, or  another way I was thinking to have it fade from one color to the image? (this way is more preferable in my opinion)